# insert a button between the images in a gallery - Android

Tags: java, android, image, android-gallery

I need to insert in a Gallery between the images spacing, buttons. Is it possible to do so? If so, I'd like to know how to implement it, and if not, I'd like to know another solution to do so (Other than using a gallery).

**Thank you!**